# Need help taking API response, converting to Pandas Dataframe, and load into an existing SQLite table

Tags: python, json, pandas, sqlite, scraper

I have been teaching myself Python for the last few weeks, and am trying to figure out how to achieve the following:

1. Run an API call
2. Take the API call response and transform into a DataFrame.
3. Take the DataFrame and load into a SQLite table

I have the first two parts down, but am stumped on the third part.

Here is what I have for parts 1 and 2:

```
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import requests

    data_request=requests.get('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs')
    json=data_request.json()
    df=pd.DataFrame(json)
```

This is what I have so far for part 3:

```
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO transactions VALUES ('')")

    conn.commit()

    conn.close()
```

I know that what I have for part 3 works, because I put sample data into the Insert clause and it works just fine. The question is, how do I get that snippet of code to take the contents of my dataframe and load it into my SQLite table instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas DataFrames's [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method. Your code would look something like:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3

data_request=requests.get('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs')
json=data_request.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(json)

conn = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')

df.to_sql('transactions', conn)

conn.close()
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: It is advised to use SQLAlchemy connection for the `to_sql` method but SQLite is the only RDBMS supporting the legacy DBAPI method (i.e., raw connection) used in your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Olzhas. I'll keep trying to troubleshoot. I get the error and a bunch of others:--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-26dbbde43cab> in <module>()
     10 conn = sqlite3.connect('transactions.db')
     11 
---> 12 df.to_sql('transactions', conn)
     13 
     14 conn.close()